# Toast View with Progress Animation Android, Left to Right

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-view

Need a solution to add a Shake View with a progress bar. This view is used as a Toast View in Android, I got a solution such that the View grows from the center and needs help in transforming into the expected result.
The current state is zipped in the drive with the actual video & expected video.

[Video and Current state source code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YT4DFEyrV1V0kDRqbLCfiq2xfqscnoPK?usp=sharing)

I tried this growFromCenter Extension function, I even tried using Object animator but got blocked while combining it with the progress bar.

```
private fun View.growFromCenter(
    duration: Long,
    @FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)
    startScaleRatio: Float,
    endAnimCallback: () -> Unit = {},
) {
    val growFromCenter = ScaleAnimation(
        startScaleRatio,
        1f,
        startScaleRatio,
        1f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.5f
    )
    growFromCenter.duration = duration
    growFromCenter.fillAfter = true
    growFromCenter.interpolator = FastOutSlowInInterpolator()
    growFromCenter.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {

        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
            endAnimCallback.invoke()
        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {

        }
    })

    startAnimation(growFromCenter)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`SnackProgressBar`](https://github.com/tingyik90/snackprogressbar) instead, I think it is better and easier to manage.

[image]

Comment: Instead of snack bar I'm looking for a View, that comes from L to R or R to L

Answer (score 3):

> Shake view with a progress bar

- **Step 1**:
  In ***res/anim*** create file ***animation.xml***

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fillAfter="true">
  <scale
   android:duration="350"
   android:fromXScale="0.0"
   android:fromYScale="0.5"
   android:pivotX="100%"
   android:pivotY="50%"
   android:toXScale="1.0"
   android:toYScale="1.0" />
  <translate
   android:duration="175"
   android:fromXDelta="0%"
   android:repeatCount="5"
   android:repeatMode="reverse"
   android:toXDelta="7%" />
  </set>
  ```
- **Step 2:** In your ***require Activity***

  ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   private val viewModel:MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()
   private  lateinit var  mBinding: ActivityMainBinding
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       mBinding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       setContentView(mBinding.root)

       viewModel.currentTime.observe(this) {
           val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(it*100)- TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
               TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(it*100)
           )
           val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(it*100)
           Log.v("timmer", "$minutes : ${seconds}")
           mBinding.progressBar.progress = it.toInt()

       }
      mBinding.btn.setOnClickListener {
           mBinding.mtrlCardChecked.visibility= View.VISIBLE
          mBinding.progressBar.visibility=View.VISIBLE
          mBinding.mtrlCardChecked.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation))
          viewModel.timer(15000L)
          mBinding.progressBar.max=15*10
       }

  }}
  ```
- **Step 3:** In ViewModel of your ***require activity***

  ```
    package com.example.toasty

   import android.os.CountDownTimer
   import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
   import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
   import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel


  class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
  private var ONE_SEC = 100L
   lateinit var mCountDownTimer: CountDownTimer

   private val _currentTime: MutableLiveData<Long> = MutableLiveData<Long>(0)
   val currentTime: LiveData<Long> = _currentTime
   fun timer(countTimer: Long) {
       mCountDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(countTimer, ONE_SEC) {
           override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
               _currentTime.value = (p0 / ONE_SEC)

           }
           override fun onFinish() {
           }
       }
       mCountDownTimer.start()
   }
  ```

  }
- **Step 4:** In your ***activity_main.xml*** file

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/ctl"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
       android:id="@+id/btn"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Hello Toasty!"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:id="@+id/mtrl_card_checked"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:visibility="gone"
       app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
       app:cardElevation="12dp"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

       <View
           android:id="@+id/v_bar"
           android:layout_width="5dp"
           android:layout_height="90dp"
           android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/progressBar"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

       <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
           android:id="@+id/iv_message_icon"
           android:layout_width="56dp"
           android:layout_height="56dp"
           android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/v_bar"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

       <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
           android:id="@+id/iv_message_icon_type"
           android:layout_width="20dp"
           android:layout_height="20dp"
           android:padding="4dp"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_message_icon"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_message_icon" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_message"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
           android:text="You have too many players in the same position. To pick another, transfer one out. (2/2)"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_message_icon"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iBtn_message_popup_close"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_message_icon"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_message_icon" />

       <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
           android:id="@+id/iBtn_message_popup_close"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="6dp"
           android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

       <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
           android:id="@+id/progressBar"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:progress="10"
           android:secondaryProgressTintMode="screen"
           app:indicatorColor="@color/teal_200"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_bar"
           app:trackColor="@color/purple_200"
           app:trackThickness="10dp" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```

[image]

You can directly download the sample project from [Github repo](https://github.com/MuhammadIbrahim001/BounceAnimation.git)

Comment: The implementation is without the exit animation, and the progress animation is not smooth. Instead of bounce apply a shake animation

Comment: Actually first you mentioned the bounce view so i did with bounce view. Now, I updated the the code for shake view.

Comment: Please update the animation.xml file with the updated code

Comment: I updated the code on repo as well

Comment: It is not smooth like the expected result: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YT4DFEyrV1V0kDRqbLCfiq2xfqscnoPK

Answer (score 0):

## After making the Custom View, You can Use below code to show that with animation

```
    val snackBarView = Snackbar.make(view, "SnackBar Message" , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    val view = snackBarView.view
    val params = view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP
    view.layoutParams = params
    view.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.custom_drawable) // for custom background
    snackBarView.animationMode = BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_FADE
    snackBarView.show()
```

below line will resolve the animation issue.

```
snackBarView.animationMode = BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_FADE
```

Alternate solution-
`snackBarView.anchorView = mention viewId above whom you want to show SnackBar`